# Output from depth sensor has lines?

Tags: azure, kinect

I started working with Kinect azure and tried some c# examples.
I noticed that the output I get has lines while the output shown on youtube from the same examples does not.
Here is an image of the output I get versus how it should look like from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HzeYb00eQRI&t=2042s) video(at 37:10).
I'm not too great at programming and this is the first time working with Kinect so I might have missed something basic, thanks in advance.

**My Output from Kinect:**

[image: my output from Kinect screenshot]

**Output from example**
[image: output from example screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Kinect is very sensitive about USB port used. It doesn't always work well even with USB chipsets that its supposed to work with.